# How to avoid the use of DataFrame.iterrows() in the following situations

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda, apply

I have the following code,

```
temp = dict()

for _, row in df_A.iterrows():
    if row["anchor"] not in temp: # anchor, id, and name are columns in df_A
        temp[row["anchor"]] = [row["id"], row["name"]]

''' Will do the same on df_B, df_B, etc... '''

 for index, row in df_Main.iterrows():
     if row["anchor"] in temp:
        self.df_Main.at[index, "id"] = temp[row["anchor"]][0]
        self.df_Main.at[index, "name"] = temp_map[row["anchor"]][1]
```

But here, `df_Main` can have more than 1 million rows and `df_A, df_B, etc...` can have 50,000 to 100,000 entries. In this case, will it be inefficient to use iterrows()?

Also, how can I do the following operations in a single line? I am fairly new to python and I don't know how to achieve my requirement using `lambda` and `apply`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first loop, you are looking for the first occurrence of `anchor` and their corresponding `id` and `name`and save them in a dictionary. You can achieve it by this line:

```
df = df_A.drop_duplicates('A', keep='first').set_index('A')
```

The second loop can be optimized like this:

```
bool_index = df_main['A'].isin(df.index)
values_A = df_main[bool_index]['A']
df_main.loc[bool_index,'B']  = df.loc[values_A,'B'].values
df_main.loc[bool_index,'C']  = df.loc[values_A,'C'].values
```

Comment: Thanks. Will this change the row order of df_Main?

Comment: No, it changes the id and name only in df_Main

Comment: There is an issue I am facing with this. If bool_index is like `True`, `False`, `True`, then in `df_Main`, only the first row's id and name are getting updated. How to solve this?

Comment: You can try it now. I fixed it :)